# Is it possible to fit an object to an arbitrary section of a curve?

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

Say I have three arrayed objects: one I want to fit to 0-38% of the curve, one from 38-75%, and one from 75-100%. Or even just one that I want to fit to 40-85%. Is this possible?

As it is, the "Fit Curve" option of the Array Modifier sets the array count to the total length of the curve. I know I can set the count to a specific length or count, but I want that length to be relative to the curve itself without being the entire length.

Also, I know I can move the object along the Curve Modifier's deformation axis to move the object along the curve, but again, that's an absolute distance rather than relative.